# HybridAuth: Authentication failed! LinkedIn returned an invalid Token

Tags: php, laravel-4, linkedin-api, hybridauth

What are possible reasons for this problem? I followed [this](http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/) totorial using HybridAuth and Laravel 4 to authenticate via LinkedIn.

I am getting this message: **Authentication failed! LinkedIn returned an invalid Token.**

Any Idea, maybe becauase of the localhost configuration?

[image]

```
**//Configuration Part**
<?php

return
array(
    "base_url" => URL::to('http://localhost:8000/social/auth'),

    "providers" => array (
        "LinkedIn" => array (
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "key" => "xxx", "secret" => "xxx"),
            "scope" => 'r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress'
        )
    ),

    // if you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true  then provide a writable file by the web server on "debug_file"
    "debug_mode" => false,

    "debug_file" => "",
); 
?>
```

At the LinkedIn Api I am getting following Keys:

**Consumer Key / API Key:**
75tgxxxasdfeulcip

**Consumer Secret / Secret Key:**
JtOXIXasdfasdfgpyFvi7

**OAuth 1.0a User Token:**
7b5955fe-6afc-4120-b148-55casdfasdf

**OAuth 1.0a User Secret:**
c7824d63-46c2-4549-bce1-8f5casdfasdf

In the HybridConfig I am using Consumer Key & Secret?! Do I have to use Oauth1.0a in the config Array?

Update: I was ending up using [Oauth2-Client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client).

best M

Comment: yes to your question; also make sure you generate new ones after posting them here...

Comment: I changed them to asdf, best M

Answer (score 0):

HybridAuth is using OAuth 1.0 so make sure you're using the OAuth 1.0a User Token and Secret generated for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that "rw_nus" is depricated i
Go to the following file
LinkedIn.php
and change the "_URL_REQUEST"

```
const _URL_REQUEST='https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+rw_nus';
```

to

```
const _URL_REQUEST='https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress';
```